# OPSHub Stuck at 3779 of 4130 Changesets

Tags: azure-devops, opshub, tfvc

Been running a migration from TFS 2010 to VSTSO overnight.  Tool has been stuck at 3779 changesets of 4130 for at LEAST an hour and a quarter, maybe more.  Anything to be done to see what is holding this up? I looked at the logs but doesn't shed any light on this for me

[image: OpshubStuck]

Comment: Longest I've had mine stuck was 7 hours. I suspect it's a Merge if you lookup the changeset number.

Comment: Check the file OpsHubTFSService.log located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs, to see which file the utility is processing, and share the log.

Comment: Yes, specifically refer the OpsHubTFSService.log in the logs folder, it should point to the operation the tool is currently performing